# Database Table Design Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I am new to DB Design and I've recently inherited the responsibility of adding some new attributes to an existing design.

Below is a sample of the current table in question:

**Submission Table:**

```
ID (int)
Subject (text)
Processed (bit)
SubmissionDate (datetime)
Submitted (bit)
...
```

The new requirements are:

1. A Submission can be marked as *valid* or *invalid*
2. A *Reason* must be provided when a Submission is marked as *invalid*. (So a submission may have an *InvalidReason*)
3. Submissions can be associated with one another such that: Multiple *valid* Submissions can be set as "replacements" for an *invalid* Submission.

So I've currently taken the *easy* solution and simply added new attributes directly to the Submission Table so that it looks like this:

**NEW Submission Table:**

```
ID (int)
Subject (text)
Processed (bit)
SubmissionDate (datetime)
Submitted (bit)
...
IsValid (bit)
InvalidReason (text)
ReplacedSubmissionID (int)
```

Everything works fine this way, but it just seems a little strange:

1. Having *InvalidReason* as a column that will be *NULL* for majority of submissions.
2. Having *ReplacedSubmissionID* as a column that will be *NULL* for majority of submissions.
3. If I understand normalization right, *InvalidReason* might be transitively dependent on the *IsValid* bit.

It just seems like somehow some of these attributes should be extracted to a separate table, but I don't see how to create that design with these requirements.

Is this single table design okay? Anyone have better alternative ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not you should have a single table design really depends on 
1) How you will be querying the data
2) How much data would end up being potentially NULL in the resulting table.

In your case its probably ok, but again it depends on #1. If you will be querying separately to get information on invalid submissions, you may want to create a separate table that references the Id of invalid submissions and the reason:

```
New table: InvalidSubmissionInfo
Id (int) (of invalid submissions; will have FK contraint on Submission table)
InvalidReason (string)
```

Additionally if you will be querying for replaced submissions separately you may want to have a table just for those:

```
New table: ReplacementSubmissions
Id (int) (of the replacement submissions; will have FK contraint on Submission table)
ReplacedSubmissionId (int) (of what got replaced; will have FK constraint on submission table)
```

To get the rest of the info you will still have to join with the Submissions table.

All this to say you do not need separate this out into multiple tables. Having a NULL value only takes up 1 bit of memory which isn't bad. And if you need to query and return an entire Submission record each time, it makes more sense to condense this info into one table.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and answer! just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Single table design looks good to me and it should work in your case.

If you do not like NULLS, you can give default value of an empty string and ReplacedSubmissionID to 0. Default values are always preferable in database design.
Having an empty string or default value will make your data look more cleaner.

Please remember if you add default values, you might need to change queries to get proper results.

For example:- 
Getting submissions which have not been replaced>

```
Select * from tblSubmission where ReplacedSubmissionID = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't fear joins. Looking for ways to place everything in a single table is at best a complete waste of time, at worst results in a convoluted, unmaintainable mess.

You are correct about *InvalidReason* and *IsValid*. However, you missed *SubmittedDate* and *Submitted*.

Whenever modeling an entity that will be processed in some way and going through consecutive state changes, these states really should be placed in a separate table. Any information concerning the state change -- date, reason for the change, authorization, etc. -- will have a functional dependency on the state rather than the entity as a whole, therefore an attempt to make the state information part of the entity tuple will fail at 2nf.

The problem this causes is shown in your very question. You already incorporated *Submitted* and *SubmittedDate* into the tuple. Now you have another state you want to add. If you had normalized the submission data, you could have simply added another state and gone on.

```
create table StateDefs(
  ID      int  auto_generated primary key,
  Name    varchar( 16 ) not null, -- 'Submitted', 'Processed', 'Rejected', etc.
  ...     -- any other data concerning states

);

create table Submissions(
  ID      int  auto_generated primary key,
  Subject varchar( 128 ) not null,
  ...     -- other data
);

create table SubmissionStates(
  SubID   int  not null references Submissions( ID ),
  State   int  not null references StateDefs( ID ),
  When    date not null,
  Description varchar( 128 )
);
```

This shows that a state consists of a date and an open text field to place any other information. That may suit your needs. If different states require different data, you may have to (gasp) create other state tables. Whatever your needs require.

You could insert the first state of a submission into the table and update that record at state changes. But you lose the history of state changes and that is useful information. So each state change would call for a new record each time. Reading the history of a submission would then be easy. Reading the *current* state would be more difficult.

But not too difficult:

```
select  ss.*
from    SubmissionStates ss
where   ss.SubID = :SubID
    and ss.When =(
        select Max( When )
        from   SubmissionStates
        where  SubID = ss.SubID
            and When <= Today() );
```

This finds the current row, that is, the row with the most recent date. To find the state that was in effect on a particular date, change *Today()* to something like *:AsOf* and place the date of interest in that variable. Storing the current date in that variable returns the current state so you can use the same query to find current or past data.

Comment: Awesome answer! This is something I definitely needed explained to me. I really like how clean and normalized this approach is, but it is slightly concerning that it makes obtaining current state (something that was basically automatic) more complex, especially when configuring ORMs.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of views. I think nothing of creating 10 or more views for every entity table. Give the app developers whatever data they need in the form most convenient for them. As the current state will be the most relevant to most needs,  create a view that lists only the current states of all the submissions. Then the query to get that data is simply "select * from view".